# Magento 2: How to repurpose the admin product image uploader?

Tags: magento2, module, admin, image-upload

Using 2.1.3, I'd like to add an image uploader to a custom admin module I'm building.

I've gotten as far as copying `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/base-image-uploader.js` to my module, renamed it and included it in my `requirejs-config.js` file - but it looks like it needs a specific `x/magento-template` to generate the uploader. (Ultimately I'll rework the ajax call to target a controller in my module as well as make additions to the success methods)

Does anyone have any tips on how to go about adding Magento 2's base image uploader to a custom module?

Comment: https://github.com/tzyganu/Magento2SampleModule This will help u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and error, adding an image uploader in the admin is fairly straight forward; create a custom js file in your module, and include "jquery/ui" and "jquery/file-uploader" into your definition:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    ....
    "jquery/ui",
    "jquery/file-uploader"
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    ...
```

And then you can reference `.fileupload({});` and attach it to any DOM element you'd like:

```
$('#domElement').fileupload({
     ....
});
```

Documentation for the fileupload configuration can be found here https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki